# Error in Starting mySql server from command prompt

Tags: mysql

I am new to sql , I installed mysql and I am following the book : Java how to program to connect to mysql

I am getting the following error. 
Regarding timestamp.. I understand the reason.. but i am trying to fix "Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Swati-HP.lower-test"

Please guide me wit respect to this

```
C:\Users\Swati>mysqld.exe
2013-10-15 13:57:01 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca
ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentati
on for more details).
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL
\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Swati-HP.lower-test
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL
\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Swati-HP.lower-test
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlo
cked functions
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [ERROR] InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write
 mode
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!

2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGIN
E failed.
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [Note] Binlog end
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
.
.
.
.
.
2013-10-15 13:57:01 7492 [Note] mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Folder "program files" in windows is usually restrict write for non-admin accounts, so you can either:

1. run mysql under admin account - not very good practice
2. set write rights for this folder for all - not very good practice
3. move data storage into another place and change my.cnf appropriately - right one

Comment: Run cmd in administrator mode by Right clicking "cmd" and selecting Run-As-Administrator

Comment: I tried to run `mysqld` command in an administrative command prompt, but it didn't work either. But, moving the installation to another folder worked well.

Answer (score 94):

The same error can also happen if `mysqld.exe` is already running. Just kill the process.

Comment: +1 - wasted half an hour and then found your answer. Cheers! I am very new to mysql. I had started the db without `--console` option.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: After i saw this I realized it was running as a service. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant read/write permissions for user SYSTEM

Answer (score 0):

Open a DOS prompt and go to the MySQL bin\ directory and issue the below command to know what is causing the issue:

..\bin > `mysqld --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --standalone --console`