# Connection fail to Mysql - ERROR 1045 - windows 8

Tags: mysql, windows

I am sure i have the correct password. When i restarted my PC i couldn't connect to MYSQLn even from the command prompt.

The error was: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Is that a problem from `WIN 8` maybe?

**UPDATE:**

Even I have used that command line (**which worked on XP**)

```
mysqld --defaults-file="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/my-default.ini" --init-file="C:\config/init.txt"
```

But in vain,

the content of init.txt is:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('123') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The log output was:

```
2013-11-25 14:46:10 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca
ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentati
on for more details).
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL
\MySQL Server 5.6\data\SFC-Laptop.lower-test
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL
\MySQL Server 5.6\data\SFC-Laptop.lower-test
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlo
cked functions
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [ERROR] InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write
 mode
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!

2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGIN
E failed.
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Binlog end
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD
'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET
'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2013-11-25 14:46:10 3288 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

**UPDATE:**

The pinging works fine also

Comment: You're describing two different problems: 1) You don't seem to know what your root password is 2) You cannot start MySQL Server from the command line, probably because your command line is not elevated

Comment: No I have the correct password of root user.
And i can start MySQL server from services. But I can get access to it

Comment: I have face the same problem,

You find you answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391182/error-in-starting-mysql-server-from-command-prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're apparently following the [How to Reset the Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html) chapter in the MySQL manual, which is a great idea. But your logs suggest that MySQL cannot write its own files:

> InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!

The problem is that the manual still does not mention User Account Control (UAC), a security mechanism introduced by Windows Vista around 2007. Even if your user is an administrator, you need to explicitly grant administrative privileges when you need them.

I don't know what it's like in Windows 8 but in Windows 7 you need to find the "Command Prompt" icon in the Start menu, right click on it and select "Run as Administrator":

[image: Run elevated command prompt]

That's called an **elevated** command prompt.